# Different behavior of function template instantiation using different compilers

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, template-instantiation

#### Description

Here' a piece of code that is treated differently by clang, gcc and msvc compilers:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>  

template <bool> struct enum_as_byte_check;
template <> struct 
[[deprecated("deprecated warning")]] enum_as_byte_check<true> {};

template <class T>
using is_scoped_enum = std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_convertible<T,int>{}
                                                  && std::is_enum<T>{}>;
template<class EnumT>
class enum_as_byte
{
    typedef enum_as_byte_check<is_scoped_enum<EnumT>::value> Check;
};

    
template<typename EnumT>
static inline void bar(const EnumT)
{
}

template<typename EnumT>
static inline void bar(enum_as_byte<EnumT>)
{
    static_assert(false && "");
}

enum class Foo : int { };
enum Bar {};
static_assert(is_scoped_enum<Foo>::value);
static_assert(!is_scoped_enum<Bar>::value);

int main() 
{
    bar<Foo>(Foo{});
}
```

Results (links lead to corresponding [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) setups):

1. [x86-64 clang 17.0.1](https://godbolt.org/z/vdYKcb9KT):

   ```
   <source>:13:10: warning: 'enum_as_byte_check<true>' is deprecated: deprecated warning [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   13 |         typedef enum_as_byte_check<is_scoped_enum<EnumT>::value> Check;
       |                 ^
   <source>:35:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'enum_as_byte<Foo>' requested here
   35 |     bar<Foo>(Foo{});
       |              ^
   <source>:35:5: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'bar' [with EnumT = Foo]
   35 |     bar<Foo>(Foo{});
       |     ^
   <source>:5:3: note: 'enum_as_byte_check<true>' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
       5 | [[deprecated("deprecated warning")]] enum_as_byte_check<true> {};
       |   ^
   ```

   1.1. if `bar<Foo>(Foo{});` [is commented:](https://godbolt.org/z/5xaxvd3qc) no warnings
2. [x86-64 clang 16.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/noYz1eMn7):

   ```
   <source>:25:5: error: static assertion failed due to requirement 'false && ""'
       static_assert(false && "");
       ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~
   <source>:13:10: warning: 'enum_as_byte_check<true>' is deprecated: deprecated warning [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
           typedef enum_as_byte_check<is_scoped_enum<EnumT>::value> Check;
                   ^
   <source>:35:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'enum_as_byte<Foo>' requested here
       bar<Foo>(Foo{});
               ^
   <source>:35:5: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'bar' [with EnumT = Foo]
       bar<Foo>(Foo{});
       ^
   <source>:5:3: note: 'enum_as_byte_check<true>' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
   [[deprecated("deprecated warning")]] enum_as_byte_check<true> {};
   ^
   ```

   2.1. [if `static_assert` is commented](https://godbolt.org/z/v5e85Krxj):

   ```
   <source>:13:10: warning: 'enum_as_byte_check<true>' is deprecated: deprecated warning [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
           typedef enum_as_byte_check<is_scoped_enum<EnumT>::value> Check;
                   ^
   <source>:35:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'enum_as_byte<Foo>' requested here
       bar<Foo>(Foo{});
               ^
   <source>:35:5: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'bar' [with EnumT = Foo]
       bar<Foo>(Foo{});
       ^
   <source>:5:3: note: 'enum_as_byte_check<true>' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
   [[deprecated("deprecated warning")]] enum_as_byte_check<true> {};
   ^
   ```

   2.2. if `bar<Foo>(Foo{});` [is commented and static_assert is not:](https://godbolt.org/z/4G5qs9z17)

   ```
   <source>:25:5: error: static assertion failed due to requirement 'false && ""'
       static_assert(false && "");
       ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~
   ```

   2.3 if both `bar<Foo>(Foo{});` and `static_assert` [are commented:](https://godbolt.org/z/hPxc41qc6):
   no warnings
3. [x86-64 gcc 13.1/13.2](https://godbolt.org/z/GT53vbTWh): no warnings
4. [x86-64 gcc 12.3](https://godbolt.org/z/6zP4nMeGe):

   ```
   <source>: In function 'void bar(enum_as_byte<EnumT>)':
   <source>:25:25: error: static assertion failed
   25 |     static_assert(false && "");
       |                   ~~~~~~^~~~~
   ```

   4.1. same output if `bar<Foo>(Foo{}());` [is commented](https://godbolt.org/z/7MPxjcxPx)

   4.2. no warnings if `static_assert` [is commented](https://godbolt.org/z/PTPjPzEqW)
5. [x86 MSVC v19.latest](https://godbolt.org/z/je7x7s17s): no warnings

#### Questions:

- Does the `enum_as_byte<EnumT>` in the definition of `bar` count as a user-defined conversion or not?
- What compiler (or compiler versions) is/are right from the standard point of view?
- What is/are the paragraph(s) from the standard that specify the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got too many things going on in that test case. Make a [minimal example!](http://sscce.org/)

The `static_assert(false)` thing is [P2593 (C++23)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2593r1.html), which some compiler releases already support and some don't. We can ignore that.

Your real question seems to be about the intended behavior of `[[deprecated]]` when it's applied to a specific *specialization* instead of to the primary template. Everyone agrees that the deprecation warning should be given for use of that specific specialization.

GCC seems to give the deprecation warning only for uses of the deprecated specialization that aren't dependent on any template parameter ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4GP87Ye4r):)

```
template<class> struct A;
template<> struct [[deprecated]] A<int> {};

template<class T>
void a() { A<T> t; }  // Clang warns (in phase 2), GCC never does

template<class T>
void b() { A<int> t; }  // Both warn (in phase 1)

void c() { A<int> t; }  // Both warn

template void a<int>();
template void b<float>();
```

Whether `A<int>` is "really used" or just used as an alias doesn't matter at all; `using U = A<int>` is still warned-about, even if `U` is never used after that. ([Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/cxqEz183b))

---

Finally, you asked:

> Does the `enum_as_byte<EnumT>` in the definition of `bar` count as a user-defined conversion or not?

No, "[user-defined] conversion" is something that *happens* during evaluation; it's not a syntactic property. Since overload resolution never selects `bar(enum_as_byte<EnumT>)`, no call to it ever happens, and so nothing ever gets converted to `enum_as_byte<EnumT>`.